# Can I watch "Now You See Me 2" without watching the first film?

Tags: now-you-see-me, suggested-order, now-you-see-me-2

I hope that this kind of question is appropriate here.

I didn't watch the first movie, *Now You See Me*, but I liked the summary of the movies, both *Now You See Me* and *Now You See Me 2*.

Is the second movie a direct sequel of the first one, or does it start anew with different context? i.e. can I watch the second movie without watching the first one?

Comment: I wouldn't, mainly because if you were to watch now you see me after 2 it would literally blow your mind, and be so confusing.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

No, you shouldn't. The second film is a direct sequel to the first film with most of the major cast returning and with a similar context. There are a few new characters and it has a new arc but it's heavily dependent on the previous film and serves as a continuation.

It takes place one year after the events happening in the previous film. And the character dynamics are mostly the same, but with some twists.

To give you more context, we can refer to [IMDb synonymous](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt3110958/) to see how much it's dependent on the previous film:

> One year after outwitting the FBI and winning the public's adulation with their Robin Hood-style magic spectacles, The Four Horsemen resurface for a comeback performance in hopes of exposing the unethical practices of a tech magnate. The man behind their vanishing act is none other than Walter Mabry, a tech prodigy who threatens the Horsemen into pulling off their most impossible heist yet. Their only hope is to perform one last unprecedented stunt to clear their names and reveal the mastermind behind it all.